# Show thumbnail in a page product

Tags: javascript, html

I have this simple code that shows the thumbnail insted of the main image, but when I want to get back to the main image it doesn´t works

JAVASCRIPT

```
let showImage = (smallImg) => {
   let fullImg = document.getElementById("imageBox");
   fullImg.src = smallImg.src;
}
```

HTML

```
<aside class="aside_left">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/skate1.jpg" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/skate2.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/skate3.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/skate4.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/skate5.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <div class="main_img">
            <img src="img/skate1.jpg" id="imageBox" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: What does not work? What does it? Do you get error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "but when I want to get back to the main image it doesn´t works" you mean that you can change to the thumbnails except for the first one then this is because you don't have a onclick on the first thumbnail like you have with the others. And you actually don't need the onclick on the main

```
<aside class="aside_left">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/skate1.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/skate2.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/skate3.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/skate4.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/skate5.jpg" onclick="showImage(this)" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
</aside>
<main>
    <div class="main_img">
        <img src="img/skate1.jpg" id="imageBox" alt="skateboard png">
    </div>
</main>
```

This should do the trick.